# MySQL fetch transaction of last 2 working days

Tags: mysql, datediff

I want to fetch transaction of last 2 working days Working day could be `TODAY & YESTERDAY` or `TODAY & DAY BEFORE YESTERDAY` or `YESTERDAY & DAY BEFORE YESTERDAY`

Table structure

```
id
title
created
```

How can i achieve that? Working day means a day with at **least 1 entry on the table**. There are multiple entries from same day.

To get distinct dates i use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as created FROM 
{Table} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Now, How can i use this sub-query to fetch all? like this

```
SELECT id FROM {Table} WHERE created IN (**sub-query**)
```

is it possible ?

Another try, but no results

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM {Table} WHERE created BETWEEN (SELECT 
DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, \'%Y-%m-%d\') FROM {Table} ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1, 1) AND (SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, \'%Y-%m-%d\') FROM 
{Table} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2, 1) ";
```

Comment: That is possible. Did you try to paste the select inside `IN` clause?

Comment: what is the format of created column and format result for your subquery?

Comment: @RxV created is  `timestamp` and subquery result is 2 dates in `Y-m-d` format

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    A.id,
    A.title,
    A.created
FROM 
    {Table} AS A 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            DATE(created) AS WorkingDay
        FROM
            {Table}
        ORDER BY 
            WorkingDay DESC
        LIMIT
            2
    ) AS B
        ON DATE(A.created) = B.WorkingDay 
ORDER BY
    A.created DESC, A.id
```

Please find **[NEW SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ea70d/2) including time parts**, which, as far as I understand the problem well, gives the expected result.

### **Query explanation**

The inner-joined query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(created) AS WorkingDay
FROM
    {Table}
ORDER BY 
    WorkingDay DESC
LIMIT
    2
```

selects distinctly from table `{Table}` 2 most recent dates (`WorkingDay`), extracting only `DATE()` part from the `created` column value. Then, after joining this result again to `{Table}` on the condition `DATE(A.created) = B.WorkingDay` top-most query returns from {Table} (aliased thi time `AS A`) only those transactions that took place on those 2 previously chosen most recent working days (`created` date).

I hope it helps some way.

Comment: Please find, if you like, the updated answer - I've tried to explain it more and provide more detailed **[SQL fiddle example query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ea70d/2)**, including time parts of `created` column. Regards.

Comment: plus one with new sql fiddle ^^

Comment: Nice Explanation, but i thing i confused you `created` column is php timestamp like this `1417090319`

Comment: @NikhilM Hi. Thank you for accepting the answer. As for `created` column, I assumed that it is a `DATETIME` MySQL type, so it can store real date-time values - however I'm not sure which default type will PHP assume on the column and how it will be presented by default. In my current PHP application I acquire DATETIME column in the following way: `SELECT ... , DATE_FORMAT(myDateTimeCol, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as f_Col ...' so in PHP, in `f_Col` I get i.e. string value `'2015-01-28 23:10:05'`, which is then converted to PHP date-time type by proper function. If I misunderstood you, please write.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you don't format properly the `created` column you just need something like this

```
SELECT id FROM {Table} WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created,'%Y-%m-%d') IN (**your subquery here**)
```

this should work. happy coding!

Comment: Does that bring all entries between those dates ? i mean the including the seconds and minutes ?

Comment: between dates only but not the time, but if you want to include time you must also include time in your subquery.